# GPS Location always remains active in notification tray after exit MapView

Tags: java, android, gps, android-mapview

***Original Title:***

> **"Location set by GPS" still remains active after**
>   **LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates()**

***Edited Title:***

> **GPS Location always remains active in notification tray after exit MapView**

I want to disable remove the "Location set by GPS" and the location icon in top notification tray **right after exit my map activity** but it doesn't.

I'm using someone's code in stackoverflow which using following variable only:

```
GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
MapView mapView;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
MapLocationListener mapLocationListener;
```

***What I've tried:***

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mapLocationListener);
        if(mGoogleApiClient != null){
            mGoogleApiClient = null;
        }
        if(mapView != null){
            mapView = null;
        }
        if(mGoogleMap != null){
            mGoogleMap = null;
        }
        if(mLocationRequest != null){
            mLocationRequest = null;
        }
        if(mLastLocation != null){
            mLastLocation = null;
        }
        if(mCurrLocationMarker != null){
            mCurrLocationMarker = null;
        }
        if(mapLocationListener != null){
            mapLocationListener = null;
        }
    }
    activity.finish();
}
```

I understand that assigning null to my references should not be the solution because the location process is running in system background not using my app references.
And **Yes**, the location listener is no longer update but it just not disable the location icon on top like other apps did. 

***What I want:***
**disable the "Location set by GPS" and the location icon in top notification tray immediately after exit my map activity**. I don't want to make my user thinks I'm doing "location hacking"
**What I've found:**
All the solution I found is using `LocationManager.removeUpdate` which I don't have it. How can I declare it in my activity? Is this can really solve my problem?

***EDIT: Attacthed Code:***
Using [Daniel Nugent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4409409/daniel-nugent)'s answer...

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;

import static android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
import static android.content.pm.PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
import static android.location.LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
import static android.location.LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;

/**
 * Created by elliotching on 11-Apr-17.
 */

public class ActivityMaps_ extends MyCustomActivity {

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    MapView mapView;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    MapLocationListener mapLocationListener;
    LocationManager locManager;

    Button buttonSaveLocation;

    double[] markerLocation;

    private final static int mapZoomLevel = 18;

    Context context = this;
    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) context;

    private class GoogleApiClientConnection implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

            Log.d("onConnected", "onConnected.");
            mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(50);
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                    ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, mapLocationListener);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        }
    }

    private class MapLocationListener implements com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // DO MY LOCATION UPDATE...
        }
    }

    private class OnMapReady implements OnMapReadyCallback {

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            Log.d("onMapReady", "onMapReady.");
            mGoogleMap = googleMap;
            mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapTouched());

            //if device OS SDK >= 23 (Marshmallow)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                //IF Location Permission already granted
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    buildGoogleApiClient();
                    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                } else {

                    // Request Location Permission
                    checkLocationPermission();

                }
            }

            //if device OS is version 5 Lollipop and below ( <= SDK_22 )
            else {

                if (checkLocationPermission_v22()) {

                    buildGoogleApiClient();
                    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                } else {

                    // AlertDialog TO EXIT MAP...

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class OnMapTouched implements GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            // CHANGE MY MARKER...
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // createMyView = setContentView(...)
        createMyView(R.layout.activity_maps, R.id.toolbar);

        mapLocationListener = new MapLocationListener();

        buttonSaveLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_save_location);
        buttonSaveLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                saveLocation();
            }
        });


        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReady());

        mapView.onResume();


    }

    private void saveLocation() {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra("savedlocation", markerLocation);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
        this.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mapLocationListener != null) {
            Log.d("FusedLocationApi", "run!");
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mapLocationListener);
        }

        activity.finish();
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {

        Log.d("buildGoogleApiClient", "buildGoogleApiClient.");
        GoogleApiClientConnection g = new GoogleApiClientConnection();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(g)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(g)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }

    private boolean checkLocationPermission_v22() {
        locManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (locManager.isProviderEnabled(GPS_PROVIDER) ||
                locManager.isProviderEnabled(NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static final int FR_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION = 99;

    private void checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, FR_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

        switch (requestCode) {
            case FR_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION: {

                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {

                    // AlertDialog to EXIT MAP...

                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 5
                && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {

            this.onPause();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            this.onPause();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this class for location tracking .

```
public class FusedLocationTracker implements LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {
    Context context;

    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    Location mCurrentLocation = null;
    private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 5;
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 1;
    String TAG = "LocationTracker";
    boolean isGPSEnabled, wifiStatus;
    WifiManager wifiManager;
    FusedLocationDataInterface fusedLocationDataInterface;

    public FusedLocationTracker(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiStatus = wifiManager.isWifiEnabled();
        if (!wifiStatus){
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
            wifiManager.startScan();
        }
        createLocationRequest();
        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }

    public void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        Log.d(TAG, "createLocationRequest");
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        Log.d(TAG, "buildGoogleApiClient");
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected");
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    public void startLocationUpdates() {
        Log.d(TAG, "startLocationUpdates");
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged");
        if (location != null) {
            fusedLocationDataInterface = (FusedLocationDataInterface) context;
            fusedLocationDataInterface.getFusedLocationData(location);
        }
    }

    public void stopLocationUpdates() {
        Log.d(TAG, "stopLocationUpdates");
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            if (!wifiStatus){
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

create interface for writing location

```
public interface FusedLocationDataInterface {
    public void getFusedLocationData(Location location);
}
```

In main activity in `onCreate()` method create object of class `FusedLocationTracker.class` and implement interface in the activity.

override this method

```
@Override
public void getFusedLocationData(Location location) {
    LatLng locate = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("My Location").position(locate));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(locate, 16.0f));
}
```

if you want to stop the locations service call the `stopLocationUpdates()`.

Comment: will `setWifiEnabled(false);` turn off the wifi?

Comment: please ignore the wifi part. if it wifi is disabled while locating it wil turn it on

Comment: One question here, your `pendingResult` is unused. Should that be in `.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, pendingResult);` ??

Comment: ok so thats mean your solution is exactly equivalent to mine `onPause`. It is not working. Sorry. Even I assigned the `removeLocationUpdates(...)` to `pendingResult` It just not the solution I want. Sorry.

Comment: For your info, I'm using MapView. Im not sure is this matter to my problem but just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
It's my fault with not getting well known understand `MapView` well. Just call `MapView.onPause()` inside my overriden `onPause()` solve the problem.